# What to do with input variables from the GUI in netlogo headless?

Tags: netlogo, headless

In the model I wrote in the GUI, there are input variables coming from the interface.
I want to run headless, should I include those variables in the code ? Assuming that the interface variables cannot be loaded ?

Moreover, to start the model, I click the `setup` button, than I click on the `go` command (which is repeated a number of time by calling it again at the end of the `go` procedure) : see below.

```
to go
;doing many thinks related to other procedure
set year year + 1
if (year = 2070) [stop]
go
end
```

My question : in the headless mode, how are launched the procedures ?
Is there a key word ?

Comment: In headless mode all of your switches, sliders, and choosers exist and can be set using `set` or using BehaviorSpace. Buttons don't exist, but all a button does when pressed is run the code in it, so you can run that same code headless, you don't need to involve a button. To run a procedure named `setup`, the code is: `setup`. That's it, you don't need a keyword.

Comment: OK, from the comment you left in another question, I undertstand that everything can indeed be set up in the Behaviour Space and then updating an .XLM "my experiment" file. However, the variable I mentioned are from "input" type of item in the interface. Should I add those global value in the code using `set` ? Is that recommended ?

Comment: Please open a new question to ask something new. (That's how Stack Overflow works.)